# Automatically saving a document from a link to a specific folder in Windows

Tags: windows, file, http, ftp

First I apologize if this is not a good place to ask this question.

So I will specify the problem:

Firm A is sending me an HTTP link that holds an excel document with price changes from the competition which I have to save to a specific folder so our Software can implement the same document into our database. Basically what we get is our current price and price of 5-8 of our competitors that are stored into the database and can be seen for each product in the database.

My question is it possible to automate saving a file from a HTTP link to a specific folder and do it few times a day so our software can load it n amount of times. Also since the name of the file is the same it needs to overwrite each time it saves the document.

The software works in a way that it is able to import excel files and update database fields properly. API in any way is not possible.

Everything needs to be done in Windows 10, for what i need to use i'm open to suggestions.

I thought about FTP access but since is outside our local network im not qualified to be absolutely sure that the connection is safe.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So what i did is use powershell:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "HTTP LINK" -OutFile "WhereToPlaceit\nameofthe.file"
```

And run task scheduler, more info here: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler

Place it on the server, and the command repeats itself each hour overwriting the existing file.